# Directed graph reduction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I know that in order to find a reduction of a directed graph, first of all we need to find all the strongly connected components of the graph. My question is, once we find all the connected components of the graph, and draw the reduction, do we still preserve the direction of the edges? Of course, assuming there are certain vertexes that are left alone, meaning are not part of any strongly connected component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about [Transitive Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction), then yes - this graph is a subgraph of the original graph, so its edges have the same orientation.